# In the deconfinement phase, there are absolutely no interactions between the particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

The Wikipedia article on Deconfinement says: "In physics, deconfinement (in contrast to confinement) is a phase of matter in which certain particles are allowed to exist as free excitations, rather than only within bound states."

Do I understand correctly that in this phase all possible interactions between quarks and gluons, as well as between quarks and quarks and between gluons and gluons, completely disappear? That is, the theory becomes free. Or is the interaction getting weak enough for the particles to move freely?

Comment: Why dont you read this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma , and partcularly this paragraph  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma#Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma_and_the_onset_of_deconfinement  to get a better feel .

Comment: @annav I read this article. Unfortunately, I did not find the answer to my question. If you know the answers, you would be of great help to me.

Comment: exactly the opposite. the QCD forces are released with a vengeance, quarks antiquars gluons contiually interacting, the electromagnetic and weak because of the small coupling constants immaterial

Comment: @annav I beg your pardon, but I almost did not understand anything.

Comment: decofinement means that instead of the quarks and gluosn being tied up in a proton or neutron or other hadron they are tied up in the plasma , quarks gluons antiquarks in a soup. This can happen only with a lot of energy, and because of QCD they continuously interact with each other.

Comment: exactly the opposite of the hypothesis in the title

Comment: @anna v If two quarks or gluons are in the same region of space, do they absolutely not interact in any way?

Comment: This might be a case of ambiguous language. In some contexts, calling a particle "free" means that it doesn't interact with anything. But the Wikipedia excerpt is using the word "free" to mean "not bound." Non-bound particles can still interact, and the quarks and gluons in the deconfinement phase certainly do interact.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress  "free excitations" , the plasma has "free excitations", not the bound states which are the protons and neutrons / rest of hadrons.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly And there are particles in nature that absolutely do not interact with anything?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress If a particle would not interact with anything there would be no way to (directly) measure it. To my knowledge there is no such particle. One could speculate that dark matter is made of particles that only interact gravitationally which is maybe the closest you can get.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Not in nature, no. But we often consider toy models that have some-but-not-all properties in common with nature. In fact, almost all of the models considered in textbooks and research articles are of this type. Models with absolutely noninteracting particles are one example: it's a mathematically easier place to start when studying quantum field theory, even though it's mostly unrealistic.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly now i understand. And, as I understand it, particles interact all the time, not just from time to time. Thanks for the answer!